# Data not getting marged in google sheet through query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q7P2DLVEh--HIE9Jibn2GrqBsqP0SYCTeM1FGHY8jw4/edit#gid=1448681395

This spreadsheet contains two sheets, `data1` and `data2`. I am trying to add both of the sheet's data into 3rd sheet named `merged`.

The problem I am facing is data from col2 (B) in data2 is being left blank in merged sheet (data2 data starts from 225 rows), also both the col2, 3 data in data2 is kind of same still column c data is being added but b is left blank.

Query being used :

```
=QUERY({data1!A:C;data2!A:C},"SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3 WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL",1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Col B of data2 is formatted as text, where as Col B of data1 is numeric. Query has issues with mixed data types. Try formatting ColB of data2 as number and see if the problem persists?

Comment: HI , I have already formated both of them as plain text , the problem is still there ,

Comment: The data in ColB of data2 still looks formatted as number. Not sure thought because I can view only. Can you allow editing rights on the spreadsheet you shared?

Comment: its working after i changed the format in both to numbers thanks